# how do I concatenate a string to my values in a column that meet a specific criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with a column called domains. Some of its values look like this: [www.name.com](http://www.name.com)
others look like this: name2.com

I want to modify the column domains, so all values in it start with www.

Comment: there might be some more clever regex solutions but simply, your criteria can be `grepl('www',name)` . It will return a boolean value that shows that is your pattern (www) in the name column or not. so your code would look like `df %>% mutate(domain =ifelse(grepl('www',yourdomaincolumn),paste0('www.',yourdomaincolumn),yourdomaincolumn)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using `baseR`

```
# Take only record that doesn't have 'www' at the beginning
the_column[!grepl("^www", the_column)] <-
   # assign them with the new value concat `www.` at the beginnning.
   paste0("www.", the_column[!grepl("^www", the_column)])
```